# Different style for menu list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following sidebar menu:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="margin-right:-2%">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    foo
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapsepro">
                    proyectos
                </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsepro" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <a href="casas.php">casas</a>
                    <a href="condominios.php">condominios</a> 
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>                   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The "li" elements have this CSS code

```
.sidebar-nav li {
text-align: center;
line-height: 65px;
font-size: 16px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: grey;
list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999999;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

How can I override the styles for

```
 <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <a href="casas.php">casas</a>
                    <a href="condominios.php">condominios</a> 
 </div>
```

to have different rules than the other "a" links, so that they look different (smaller, less line space, etc.)? So basically change the style of the accordion items. I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below class to sytle the links within 'accordion-inner' div

```css
.sidebar-nav li #collapsepro .accordion-inner a{
    /* Your style goes here. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.accordion-inner a{
    font-size: smaller !important;
    line-height: 10px !important;
    ...other styles
}
```

`!important` will override any other styles applied to the anchors whether directly or inherited.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the !important attribute